# Publish website from google scripts to everyone

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, publish

I created a simple website from google sheets scripts to show the current ranking of a local tournament.
The data constantly gets updated in the regarding spreadsheet.
The plan is that the spectators can scan a bar code with the address and see the standings.
But I couldn't figure out how to publish this site to people without a google account.
I just can choose between "for me" and "for everyone with a google account" (translated freely because I use the GUI in german).
The page works fine with a google account on the receiving side.
Can you help me?

Just for completeness.
The Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log(getData());
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}
 

function getData(){
  console.log("data read started");
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Ergebnisse");
  var dataRange     = "Ergebnisse!A4:N50";
 
  let values = [];
  for(i = 5; i <= 50; i++) {
    let time = spreadSheet.getRange(`K${i}`).getValue();
    time = time.toString().substring(16,24);
    if(spreadSheet.getRange(`A${i}`).getValue() != "") {
      values.push([
        spreadSheet.getRange(`A${i}`).getValue(), 
        spreadSheet.getRange(`B${i}`).getValue(),
        spreadSheet.getRange(`D${i}`).getValue(),
        spreadSheet.getRange(`E${i}`).getValue(),
        spreadSheet.getRange(`G${i}`).getValue(),
        spreadSheet.getRange(`H${i}`).getValue(),
        spreadSheet.getRange(`J${i}`).getValue(),
        time,
        spreadSheet.getRange(`L${i}`).getValue(),
        spreadSheet.getRange(`N${i}`).getValue(),
      ]);
    }
  }

  return values;
}
```

The Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">

    <script>
      $(function() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();
      });

      function showData(dataArray) {
        console.log("Starte Tabellendarstellung");
        $.each(dataArray, (index, row) => {
          let $tr = $('<tr/>');
          $.each(row, (index, val) => {
            $tr.append(
              $('<td/>', {text: val})
            );
          });
          $('#dataTable tbody').append($tr);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
 
  <body>
    <div>
      <table class="table table is-striped table is-fullwidth" id="dataTable">
          <thead>
            <th>Athlet</th>
            <th>Snatch</th>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>C&J</th>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Squat</th>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>WoD</th>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Gesamtplatz</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I just want that everyone with or without a google account can see the standings.

Comment: @Martheen unfortunately not.
I just can choose between "Me" and "Everybody with a google account"

Comment: Well, there's the answer, it's simply not available anymore or for your type of app.

Comment: Oh that´s a bummer :(
Thank you!

Comment: It is available. You need to contact your admin. cc:@Martheen